# Disconnect and reconnect wifi via command line

Tags: raspberry-pi

I need to disconnect and reconnect the wifi of my RaspberryPi (Ubuntu) via SSH in order to test the error handling. I'm using:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down && ifconfig wlan0 up
```

However, the connection does not appear to be reactivated, since I have to reboot it manually (unplug and plug back in) in order to be able to connect again via ssh. Otherwise, it just says

```
ssh pi@raspberrypi
ssh: connect to host raspberrypi port 22: Connection timed out
```

Comment: No `ifup`/`ifdown` present?

Comment: What does this mean?

Comment: `ifconfig` is a rather dated command, AFAIK it for example doesn't start a DHCP process. Run `ifup wlan0` instead of `ifconfig wlan0 up`